# How do you specify demands on a TFS Release?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

**Background:** I'm using on-prem TFS 2015. I have two build agents. As part of my build and release process I want to run some PowerShell modules that are registered on one agent but not one the other. I've set up capabilities on the agent and demands on the build so that the build runs on a particular agent. But now I need to run the release and specify the same agent.

**Question:** How do I set up my release to run on a particular agent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it. It's on the Trigger Tab. Select "Edit" pencil icon in Environmental triggers.

[image]

[image]

You can also edit it if you click on this:

[image]